# Converting ISO-8601 Timestamp

Tags: javascript, iso8601

Is there a JavaScript library function that converts an [IS0-8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) time-formatted String:

`2015-01-27T00:00:00.328Z`

into a String with the following format:

`'YYYY.MM.DD HH:MI:SS'`?

Example:

`convert("2015-01-27T00:00:00.328Z") === "2015.01.27 00:00:00.328"`

Comment: You don't need a library, though moment.js can do this. Hint: `new Date('1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to be using dates more than a simple conversion, you might want to consider using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com).

```
moment('2015-01-27T00:00:00.328Z').format('YYYY.MM.DD HH:mm:ss'); //Output depends on your timezone
```

By default moment uses your local time for displaying. If this is not the desired behavior, you can instead use

```
moment.utc('2015-01-27T00:00:00.328Z').format('YYYY.MM.DD HH:mm:ss'); //"2015.01.27 00:00:00"
```

Or if you want to include milliseconds:

```
moment.utc('2015-01-27T00:00:00.328Z').format('YYYY.MM.DD HH:mm:ss.SSS'); //"2015.01.27 00:00:00.328"
```

Comment: Thanks, Nit. However, I also want to capture the 3 trailing seconds. They're trimmed from the `format("... HH:MM:SS")` part.

Comment: I've fixed a formatting bug in the answer, I mixed up `SS` and `ss` since I wrote the answer off the top of my head. Note however that in your sample value there aren't 3 seconds, it's 300 milliseconds. Are you sure it's what you want? If so, how do you want to format the output?

Comment: I believe that I want: `moment(INPUT).utc().format('YYYY.MM.DD HH:mm:sss.SSS')`

Comment: @KevinMeredith How does that make sense? Specifying `sss` is saying seconds can take up three digits, which will never be the case. I've updated the answer to include milliseconds, though.